# Centering an image larger than browser window, which can then be used as a rollover image

Tags: image, rollover, image-size

I should start by saying I'm relatively new to the likes of HTML/CSS. I have an image that is 2880x540 and I'm looking to set it as the landing page for a website. This means I need to have the image centered so that the excess width bleeds off the browser window, without having a scrollbar (the excess resolution is there for the likes of higher resolution monitors). I'm planning on using two regions of the image as rollovers for two other images that have the same proportions.

As of right now my code is very basic:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <img src="sitewide.png" width="2880" height="540"  alt=""/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your image as a centered background of a div:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body{
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }
      #bigImage{
        background:url('sitewide.png') no-repeat top center;
        width: 2880px;
        height: 540px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bigImage"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did remove the scroll bar. However I'd still like to somehow lock the image to the center of a browser. The usual HTML methods of centering simply don't work on larger images so I'm not sure how to go about doing it with CSS.

Comment: @ZacharyShampine you're welcome. just add a `text-align:center;` to your css, it should work. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Nasser, but that's still butting the left edge of the image up against the left side of the browser.

Comment: @ZacharyShampine so the only thing I can think of is to set your image as background of a div, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll give that ago. If anyone else has any suggestions they'd be greatly appreciated.